# Herkou class changes not detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku

I'm using Herkou for some Rails 3 hosting. I have pushed code to Heroku, and I am getting the following error from the logs:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `format_date' for #<Project:0x00000001938f40>):
```

This method does exist! I can for example so this:

```
$heroku console

>> Project.format_date('2011-07-07 10:50')
=> "2011-07-07"
```

So my code appears to be deployed. `Project` responds to `format_date`.

I also tried `heroku restart` with no success.

Can anyone help me? Any and all suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are calling format_date on the class itself, like you do in your example,  and not on an instance of the class? I.e. `Project.new.format_date("2011-07-07 10:50")`

Comment: Spot on. I found an instance of that, fixed it and we're good to go. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to have been of service :)